# What's the Java data type correspondent to postgreSQL's DECIMAL in JPA?

Tags: postgresql, jpa, orm

```
CREATE TABLE band (
    length      DECIMAL(6, 3) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    resolution  DECIMAL(4, 1)             NOT NULL
);
```

I have this table defined in my **postgreSQL** database and I'm using **JPA** for my application. What data type should I use in the attribute of the object corresponding to `Length`? I tried using `double` but I got the following error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [length] in table [band]; found [numeric (Types#NUMERIC)], but expecting [float8 (Types#DOUBLE)]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`java.math.BigDecimal`

From [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTinsk4rwT7v-751bwQkgTN1rkA=8uE-jk69nape-@mail.gmail.com)

Answer (score 1):

`double` is perfectly mappable on to DECIMAL in many JPA providers. But then so is `float`. `BigDecimal` is another option.

If having a problem with that I suggest that you raise a bug in your JPA provider, or define the "columnDefinition" info in the JPA `@Column` annotation

Comment: postgreSQL's decimal will lose precision if mapped to a double.

Comment: Except that he has precision 6,3 and a double can handle that!

Comment: double can give (known from half century) errors in financial computing, and DECIMAL PRIMARY KEY column suggest such application with exact computing

Comment: sure but then you use String as an option, and can't do other operations. Your comment is really a comment to the OP, not to this answer ;-)